# How do I use axios response in different components without using export?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

As the tittle says, I would like to be able to use the same axios response for differents components.
I have some restrictions like, I'm onlyl able to use react by adding scripts tags to my html so things like exports or jsx are impossible for me.

This is my react code:

```
    class User extends React.Component {

      state = {
        user: {}
      }

    componentWillMount() {
      console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"))
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/dashboard?user=' + localStorage.getItem("user"))
      .then(res => {
        const userResponse = res.data
        setTimeout(() =>
       this.setState({user: userResponse.user}), 1000);
      })
    }

      render () {
        const {user} = this.state
        if (user.fullName === undefined)
        return React.createElement("div", null, 'loading..');


        return React.createElement("span", {className: "mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small" }, user.fullName);
      }

    }

    ReactDOM.render( React.createElement(User, {}, null), document.getElementById('userDropdown') );

class Roles extends React.Component{

  state = {
    user: {}
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"))
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/dashboard?user=' + localStorage.getItem("user"))
    .then(res => {
      const userResponse = res.data
      setTimeout(() =>
      this.setState({user: userResponse.user}), 1000);
    })
  }

  render () {
    const {user} = this.state
    const roles = user.user.roles.map((rol) =>  rol.roleName)

    if (user.fullName === undefined)
    return React.createElement("div", null, 'loading..');

    return React.createElement("a", {className: "dropdown-item" }, user.fullName);
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( React.createElement(Roles, {}, null), document.getElementById('dropdownRol') );
```

I would like to be able to manage different components(rendering each one) with data of the same axios response.

Is this possible considering my limitations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have one component that does the loading and then passes the data to its children as props. Or you could have a Store class that does the loading and the other components could get the data from the store as needed.

Comment: In your code, which component is making the request and which component needs the response?

Comment: I edited my code to show what I would like to achieve. For example that one component do a request and use the response, and a second component that uses the same response. Both should be able to render data.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of how you might do it. I've tried to annotate everything with comments, but I'm happy to try to clarify if you have questions.

```js
// Fake response object for the store's "load" request
const fakeResponse = {
  user: {
    fullName: "Carolina Ponce",
    roles: [
      { roleName: "administrator" },
      { roleName: "editor" },
      { roleName: "moderator" },
      { roleName: "generally awesome person" }
    ]
  }
};

// this class is responsible for loading the data
// and making it available to other components.
// we'll create a singleton for this example, but
// it might make sense to have more than one instance
// for other use cases.
class UserStore {
  constructor() {
    // kick off the data load upon instantiation
    this.load();
  }

  // statically available singleton instance.
  // not accessed outside the UserStore class itself
  static instance = new this();

  // UserStore.connect creates a higher-order component
  // that provides a 'store' prop and automatically updates
  // the connected component when the store changes. in this
  // example the only change occurs when the data loads, but
  // it could be extended for other uses.
  static connect = function(Component) {
    // get the UserStore instance to pass as a prop
    const store = this.instance;

    // return a new higher-order component that wraps the connected one.
    return class Connected extends React.Component {
      // when the store changes just force a re-render of the component
      onStoreChange = () => this.forceUpdate();

      // listen for store changes on mount
      componentWillMount = () => store.listen(this.onStoreChange);

      // stop listening for store changes when we unmount
      componentWillUnmount = () => store.unlisten(this.onStoreChange);

      render() {
        // render the connected component with an additional 'store' prop
        return React.createElement(Component, { store });
      }
    };
  };

  // The following listen, unlisten, and onChange methods would
  // normally be achieved by having UserStore extend EventEmitter
  // instead of re-inventing it, but I wasn't sure whether EventEmitter
  // would be available to you given your build restrictions.

  // Adds a listener function to be invoked when the store changes.
  // Called by componentWillMount for connected components so they
  // get updated when data loads, etc.
  // The store just keeps a simple array of listener functions. This
  // method creates the array if it doesn't already exist, and
  // adds the new function (fn) to the array.
  listen = fn => (this.listeners = [...(this.listeners || []), fn]);

  // Remove a listener; the inverse of listen.
  // Invoked by componentWillUnmount to disconnect from the store and
  // stop receiving change notifications. We don't want to attempt to
  // update unmounted components.
  unlisten = fn => {
    // get this.listeners
    const { listeners = [] } = this;

    // delete the specified function from the array.
    // array.splice modifies the original array so we don't
    // need to reassign it to this.listeners or anything.
    listeners.splice(listeners.indexOf(fn), 1);
  };

  // Invoke all the listener functions when the store changes.
  // (onChange is invoked by the load method below)
  onChange = () => (this.listeners || []).forEach(fn => fn());

  // do whatever data loading you need to do here, then
  // invoke this.onChange to update connected components.
  async load() {
    // the loading and loaded fields aren't used by the connected
    // components in this example. just including them as food
    // for thought. components could rely on these explicit fields
    // for store status instead of pivoting on the presence of the
    // data.user object, which is what the User and Role components
    // are doing (below) in this example.
    this.loaded = false;
    this.loading = true;

    try {
      // faking the data request. wait two seconds and return our
      // hard-coded data from above.
      // (Replace this with your network fetch.)
      this.data = await new Promise(fulfill =>
        setTimeout(() => fulfill(fakeResponse), 2000)
      );

      // update the loading/loaded status fields
      this.loaded = true;
      this.loading = false;

      // call onChange to trigger component updates.
      this.onChange();
    } catch (e) {
      // If something blows up during the network request,
      // make the error available to connected components
      // as store.error so they can display an error message
      // or a retry button or whatever.
      this.error = e;
    }
  }
}

// With all the loading logic in the store, we can
// use a much simpler function component to render
// the user's name.
// (This component gets connected to the store in the
// React.createElement call below.)
function User({ store }) {
  const { data: { user } = {} } = store || {};

  return React.createElement(
    "span",
    { className: "mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small" },
    user ? user.fullName : "loading (User)…"
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  // Connect the User component to the store via UserStore.connect(User)
  React.createElement(UserStore.connect(User), {}, null),
  document.getElementById("userDropdown")
);

// Again, with all the data loading in the store, we can
// use a much simpler functional component to render the
// roles. (You may still need a class if you need it to do
// other stuff, but this is all we need for this example.)
function Roles({ store }) {
  // get the info from the store prop
  const { data: { user } = {}, loaded, loading, error } = store || {};

  // handle store errors
  if (error) {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "oh noes!");
  }

  // store not loaded yet?
  if (!loaded || loading) {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "loading (Roles)…");
  }

  // if we made it this far, we have user data. do your thing.
  const roles = user.roles.map(rol => rol.roleName);

  return React.createElement(
    "a",
    { className: "dropdown-item" },
    roles.join(", ")
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  // connect the Roles component to the store like before
  React.createElement(UserStore.connect(Roles), {}, null),
  document.getElementById("dropdownRol")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="userDropdown"></div>
<div id="dropdownRol"></div>
```