# Having issues trying to store data using state in React so that it is accessible later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I'm writing a React app to pull specific data from an API done through search (forms), storing it and manipulating it using filters and what not. So far I have pulled the data and displayed it, but I just cannot work out how to store it using state so that I can access it without having to do an entirely new data pull.

So far I have tried returning the API data to be stored in a list locally inside the function, but then I have zero access to manipulate it moving forward. I think I need 'list' with name and age stored in state, and then accessed, but I just can't work out how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function dataPull(param) {

    const list = [
        { name: '', age: ''}
    ]

    const URLbase = "https://APIexample.com";
    const query = URLbase + param;
    const URL = URLbase + param;

    fetch(URL)
       .then(fnc(res) {
           let text = document.getElementById('textSpot');
           res.map(res => (
              <list key={res.name} age={res.age} />
           ));
           text.innerHTML = res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM or setting `innerHTML` in a react app.

If you want to store the data in component state, do the fetch in the [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method (or equivalent hook) and then call `this.setState({results: fetchedData})`. Your render method can then get the data via `this.state.results` and render accordingly. (See example below.)

If you want to use the data beyond just this component you might want to consider implementing a data store independent of the component. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161159/636077) of how you might do that.

```js
const fakeData = [
  {
    name: "chewy",
    age: 900
  },
  {
    name: "chewbacca",
    age: 40
  }
];

// wait a second and then resolve with fakeData
const fakeFetch = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(fakeData), 1000);
})

class Wookies extends React.Component {
    state = {}

    componentDidMount () {
      fakeFetch()
        .then(result => this.setState({result}));
    }

    render () {
      const {result} = this.state;
      
      if (!result) {
        // not loaded. render loading spinner or whatever.
        return <div>loading</div>;
      }

      return result.map(item => (
        <div key={item.name}>age: {item.age}</div>
      ));
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Wookies />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function dataPull(param) {

    const list = [
        { name: '', age: ''}
    ]

    const URLbase = "https://APIexample.com";
    const query = URLbase + param;
    const URL = URLbase + param;

    fetch(URL)
       .then(fnc(res) {
           let text = document.getElementById('textSpot');
           let items = [];
           items = res.map(res => (
              <list key={res.name} age={res.age} />
           ));
           text.innerHTML = items;
}
```